# How can I remove the specific character from href link?

Tags: javascript, string

My link is `https://mytestsite.com/search/label/interesting?m=1`

How can I remove the `?m=1` from end of link?

Comment: Can you not just remove it from the source?

Comment: do a redirect if m is present

Comment: You can split the url at the `?` char. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this

```js
var address = "https://mytestsite.com/search/label/interesting?m=1";
var pieces = address.split('?')[0];

// to show address after being sliced
alert(pieces);
```

Comment: Why add the unrequited and un requested jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the url at `?` character.

```
var link = 'https://mytestsite.com/search/label/interesting?m=1';
var arr = link.split('?');
console.log(arr[0]);
```

In `arr[0]` you will get result - `https://mytestsite.com/search/label/interesting`

Answer (score -1):

```
    var str = "https://mytestsite.com/search/label/interesting?m=1";
    str = str.slice(0, -4);
```